# Delete fields that have a specific substring on logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash

I want to delete the fields which the value has a specific substring.

I have this code:

```
ruby {
            code => "
                event.each do |key, value|
                    if value =~ /substring/
                        event.delete(key)
                  end
                end
            "
          }
```

I am getting a ruby exception on tags and I don't know why.
Thanks!

Comment: What would be an example value of `event`?

Answer (score 0):

One can not modify a hash while iterating it.

```
event.reject! { |_, value| value =~ /substring/ }
```

The above should do.